# Can you get support access to subscriber sandbox?

Tags: managed-package, sandbox

I wanted to know if you can get access to subscriber sandbox during the initial installation of a managed package.

Also if the subscriber does not have access to production data in the sandbox , are there any options to get some of the production data into a sandbox?

Comment: They can grant you access just like they do in prod. Data is the same issue as without your package. They need to create the sandbox with it or load it

Comment: Thanks  Eric! The subscriber has partial copy sandbox and does not know how to create a copy of data. Can I get access to load data in the sandbox?

Comment: Depends on where the data is. If you have a Csv  and their permission, create a user for yourself while logged in via the lma. If they created a partial it should have data

Comment: I see. If they do not have data in the partial copy, is there a quick way to copy some data from production to sandbox without recreating the sandbox?